# react native prop allowFontScaling not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, android-layout, android-activity, react-redux

I'm new in **react-native** and want to fix text size in all screens of app if I increase text size from device settings then also font size of should be same I had tried:

```
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling=false;
```

in android.index.js
and

```
public void adjustFontScale(Context context, Configuration configuration) {
    configuration.fontScale =(float) 0.85;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);

}
```

in mainactivity.js called in `oncreate()` after `super.onCreate();`

and also custom theme linked from AndroidManifest.xml not worked

if someone is having another solution for this please help me.

its working perfectly on ios device.

Answer (score 5):

(Should be a comment, but I haven't the rep!)

Seems to be some bugs with the Font Scaling, take a look at a few issues here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18827

Someone comments:

> Also in React Native 0.56.0 setting TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false; doesn't work at all.

There is a library someone has created for this issue, however I have not tested this:

https://github.com/NelGarbuzova/react-native-stylized-placeholder

UPDATE : I've tested this on my Android emulator and it works as below:

```
"react": "16.3.0-alpha.0",
"react-native": "0.55.0",


public render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text allowFontScaling={false}>Text Scaling</Text>
            <Text>No Text Scaling</Text> 
        </View>
    )
}
```

The Result is below on a Pixel 2 (running 28)

[image]

Comment: still its not fixed.

Comment: What version of React Native are you using? I'll give it a go on my android device later

Comment: RN version I am using is 0.55 and I had tried on 0.56 also

Comment: Did you try the library?

Comment: I'll give it a go today for you.

Comment: @prabhat I've updated my answer for you, if you're still having issues let me know, if not, please accept the answer